# Is Notification.Builder.setTicker still useful in Android 5 and above?

Tags: android

My understanding of the [Notification.Builder.setTicker(ticketText:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method is that it will show text in the status bar even without the user having to "pull down" the incoming notification.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) describes this method as follows:

> Set the "ticker" text which is sent to accessibility services.

On Android 5+ devices, the ticket text no longer shows in the status bar when there is an incoming notification. (It only shows a single app icon.)

I was wondering: Does the [Notification.Builder.setTicker(ticketText:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method still have other usage on Android 5+ devices?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it still does. Please see the description of the [Notification.ticketText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#tickerText) property.

If you were to turn on accessibility services on your device (for like visually challenged people), the text passed into the [Notification.Builder.setTicker(ticketText:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method will be audibly announced.

The [Notification.Builder.setTicker(ticketText:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTicker%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method only has usage with accessibility services enabled. It does not show a text in the status bar.

Comment: what, do you mean by that? so, its foreground service? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: If the service generating the notification has been asked to run in the foreground then yes, it is a foreground service

Answer (score 3):

To reactivate showing text in status bar:

```
notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```