# notifications for and above lollipop upto and for nougat auto hide not working

Tags: android, notifications

I am searching for a appropriate solution since a month for this problem, but no other than [Is Notification.Builder setTicker still useful in Android 5 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725102/is-notification-builder-setticker-still-useful-in-android-5-and-above) is available on `stack overflow` from which i can learn. I also tried many threads and its answers by experts here.. But now i think i have to put my question here.. As my application is in deployment phase.

---

I am running a service in background, which shows multiple notifications to user. `onStartCommand` is having `runnable thread` which keeps running for specific events after a sleep of `Thread.sleep(10000);`, and if notification is already shown then i am not showing it again by assigning  `Boolean variables for each notifications to true` and checking that variables wherever notification is needed to be shown. Everything is working perfect as i want..!! :)

---

This is how notifications are built and shown :

```
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
                .setContentText("Get details here..")
                .setTicker("Get details here..")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setPriority(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {

            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
```

---

This is how later notifications are showing :

```
if (!Notif_One)
{
    Notif_One = true;
    mBuilder.setContentText("ERROR, UNINSTALL APP..");
    mBuilder.setTicker("ERROR, UNINSTALL APP..");

    mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                            startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
}
```

---

What is problem :

1. `Below Lollipop` it is showing animated ticker, default sound and default vibration.. All OKAY.
2. `Lollipop` `Marshmallow` and `Nougat` not showing any animated ticker text..!!
3. `Oreo` popping down beautiful heads up notification and popping up / hiding it again automatically very nicely.

I know for heads up notification above `Lollipop` needs `Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` and `Vibrate` to work..., If i makes such changes, then its behaviour is like :

1. `Below Lollipop` it is showing animated ticker, default sound and default vibration.. All OKAY.
2. `Lollipop` `Marshmallow` and `Nougat` popping down the notification but not again automatically hiding it into status bar. How should i make it auto hide OR show ancient beautiful animated ticker notification text.
3. `Oreo` popping down beautiful heads up notification and popping up / hiding it again automatically very nicely.

---

I hope i have asked very neat question, which is not duplicate, which is abiding to all forum rules, which is important to be here on stackoverflow for many users running a `foreground service.` with `many notifications`. 
Thank you stackoverflow and developers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have solved the issue and I think it would be helpful to someone else having the same issue in showing notifications from a foreground service.

---

My service class variables declared are

```
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "17";
```

---

My service class `onCreate()` is making first notification like

```
try
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Insta Promo")
                .setContentText("Get details here..")
                .setTicker("Get details here..")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {

            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        startForeground(17, mBuilder.build());


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("xx", "EXCEPTION IN SHOWING NOTIFICATION...\n");
        Log.e("xx", "Exception is : ", e);
    }
```

---

thereafter whenever i need to replace existing notification with another

```
mBuilder.setContentText("PLEASE ALLOW PERMISSIONS...");
mBuilder.setTicker("PLEASE ALLOW PERMISSIONS...");
mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
startForeground(17, mBuilder.build());
```

---

If you want to stop foreground service but keep notifications then

```
stopForeground(false);
```

and do not call `stopself()`

Instead from mainactivity `OnDestroy` Stop this service and clear the notification channel

---

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: Below 5.0 it shows ticker text notification and on or above 5.0 it shows heads up notification and automatically hides after some time, into status bar. and it shows notifications on lock screen too..!!